# switching from $resource to Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

i read good things about restangular, but i don't know how to switch from my current config which is using $resource.

**here is my actual setup working with $resource :**

inside the service.js:

```
.factory('List', function($resource) {
    return $resource('relative/url/to/json/:type/:id', { type:'@type', id:'@id' });
})
```

two different controllers use this service :

• the "detail" controller

```
.controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'List', function($scope, $routeParams, List) {
    var p = {'type': $routeParams.type, "id": $routeParams.id };
    List.get(p, function(detail, responseHeaders) { // success callback
        $scope.detail = detail; 
        // do something with responseHeaders
    });
}])
```

• the "list" controller:

```
.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'List', function($scope, List) {
    var params = { sort: 'DESC', limit: 8 }; 
    $scope.loadList = function (type, params) {
        params.type = type; 
        List.query(params, function(list, responseHeaders) { // success callback
            $scope.list = list; 
            // do something with responseHeaders
        });
    }
}])
```

**i want to replace all the $resource stuff with restangular.**

after configuration, Restangular is fetching the datas in a basic way, like this :

• inside the "detail" controller

```
$scope.elm = Restangular.one($routeParams.type, $routeParams.id).get();
```

• inside the "list" controller

```
var params = { sort: 'DESC', limit: 8};
$scope.loadList = function (type, params) {
    $scope.list = Restangular.all(type).getList(params);
}
```

this is working. but now :

**1. how is it possible to get the response headers ?**

**2. how is it possible to send the datas to the scope inside a success callback function ?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose it's too late for you, but maybe this can help others.

For question #1, I've found this at [restangular github](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setfullrequestinterceptor) :

> setFullRequestInterceptor
>
> The fullRequestInterceptor is similar to the requestInterceptor but
>   more powerful. It lets you change the element, the request parameters
>   and the headers as well.
>
> It's a function that receives the same as the requestInterceptor plus
>   the headers and the query parameters (in that order).
>
> It must return an object with the following properties:
>
> headers: The headers to send
>
> params: The request parameters to send
>
> element: The element to send
>
> httpConfig: The httpConfig to call with

You can do it this way (edit: I think in this function you can also set scope data, changing code):

```
Restangular.setFullResponse(true);
Restangular.setResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
   var contentType = response.headers['Content-Type']; // this to get content-type
   var status = response.headers['Status']; // here we obtain the http response status

   // now we can mount our own js object to return all we need
   // i.e.: the status, content-type and response data to be processed into another function
   var myArray = [contentType, status, response.data];
   // i think we can also set scope data
   $scope.myData = response.data;

   return myArray;
});
```